# How to open a source file by name in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the `Developer Tools` is there a way to enter the name (or part thereof) to find specific source files - such as `.js`, `.css`, etc?

I would like to find `myJs.js` but am uncertain how to do so without manually traversing the sources navigator panel on the left.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like Ctrl-O. You can view all shortcuts in devtools settings.